# In a for loop containing a loop expression that uses the length of a string, does modifying the string in the loop body update the string length?

Tags: for-loop, c++17

I am trying to make a function that will read two input strings and figure out if they are anagrams of one another (in other words, that will return true if the strings are of the same length and contain the same number and type of characters). I tried achieving this with nested for loops, but I've generated an error saying: "libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string".

I've taken this to mean one of my for loops is trying to utilize a non-existent index from one of my strings, but I'm not fully sure why this is the case.

This is my code thus far:

```
bool isAnagram(string firstString="", string secondString="") {
    //Initialize variables.
    cin >> firstString >> secondString;
    string copySecondString = secondString;
    int matchedChars = 0;

    //Check if string lengths are equal
    if (firstString.size() != secondString.size()) {
        return false;
    }

    // Outer for loop iterates through each character in firstString
    // Inner while loop iterates through each character in copySecondString
    for (int i = 0; i < firstString.size(); i++) {
        for (int copyIndex = 0; copyIndex < copySecondString.size(); copyIndex += 1) {
            //Check if index of copySecondString matches i
            if (firstString.at(i) == copySecondString.at(copyIndex)) {
                matchedChars += 1;
                copySecondString.erase(copySecondString.at(copyIndex));
                cout << copySecondString.size();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (matchedChars == firstString.size()) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now, I'm sure this looks quite amateurish and inefficient in some way, and that's a fair assessment, since I'm just starting out coding. Rather than have my entire approach be corrected (which I may ask for help with in a later, separate question), I'm simply trying to figure out why this code as written is failing. I suspect the issue has to do with my inner for loop, since I wind up (I think) deleting characters from the string referenced in its loop expression as I go, and maybe that somehow results in copyIndex exceeding the length of copySecondString down the road. But I don't actually *know* this because I can't quite make sense of that happening in my head. Can anyone point out why this is going wrong?

Comment: Doesn't `erase` take an index?

Comment: I believe it does. Looking back, string.at(x) gives the character at index x, not literally the index, right? Maybe I should only have copySecondString.erase(copyIndex), then.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are character arrays, so if your strings are out of range, you call a pointer that exceeds the maximum range of the array. Characters can be extracted with square brackets `[]`.

`.at` functions are unnecessary as your for loop auto increments after each pass, therefore square brackets will do the job. Your `erase` function removes elements from the `copySecondString` string, shortening the array size. Yet the copyIndex keeps increasing, this leads to characters in `copySecondString` being skipped as well as `copyIndex` exceeding the maximum size of `copySecondString`, thus causing the `out_of_range` error message to pop up.

Here's a corrected version

```
bool isAnagram() {
//Initialize variables within the function, unless the values are parsed from other components of your code
String firstString, secondString
cin >> firstString >> secondString;
string copySecondString = secondString;
int matchedChars = 0;

//Check if string lengths are equal
if (firstString.size() != secondString.size()) {
    return false;
}

// Outer for loop iterates through each character in firstString
// Inner while loop iterates through each character in copySecondString
for (int i = 0; i < firstString.size(); i++) {
    for (int copyIndex = 0; copyIndex < copySecondString.size(); copyIndex++) {
        //Check if index of copySecondString matches i
        if (firstString[i] == copySecondString[copyIndex]) {
            matchedChars ++;
            cout << copySecondString.size() - copyIndex;
            //this outputs the same value as copySecondString.erase
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (matchedChars == firstString.size()) {
    return true;
}
```

}